# Java 8 Stream of LocalDateTime, how to find list of them without looping all

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a list/stream of Java 8 `LocalDateTime` (timestamp) which is in the ascending(chronological) order.

```
2019-03-01T13:13:13
2019-03-01T15:15:15
2019-03-02T12:12:12
2019-03-02T14:14:14
2019-03-03T11:11:11
2019-03-03T08:08:08
```

How can I quickly find out sublist of it which are within a given 12 hours period **without looping for all the elements of list**. I know it will be simple just do a filter but which would loop the whole list (assume the list is quite big)

If the start timestamp is `2019-03-01T10:10:10`, then the end timestamp is `2019-03-01T22:22:21`

The sublist of timestamp must be after start and before the end.

Comment: If you use streams, any search has to be linear. If the list is array-based, you can use the binary search functions in `Arrays`.

Comment: If they are in ascending chronological order you can exit from the loop when you meet the first timestamp >= start timestamp. Then you can do the same thing looping in the reverse order.

Comment: If you were using Java 9+, and you needed/wanted to use streams, I'd say use [`Stream.dropWhile(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) in combination with [`Stream.takeWhile(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)).

Comment: If the `List` is an `ArrayList` and sorted, you can find the smallest element larger than `startTime` and the largest element smaller than `endTime` in `log(n)`. Thus, the search takes only `log(n)`, where `n` is the list size. Without further information, however, no further estimation for the copy operation can be made and must thus be estimated with complexity `n`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There's also [`Collections.binarySearch(List,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)).

Comment: @Slaw "*This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the `RandomAccess` interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.*"

Comment: @Slaw yes, the same principle - the list has to be random-access (which usually means, array-based).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Agreed. I just thought I'd mention it as your comment could be interpreted as saying only `Arrays` provides such functionality—which would require converting the list into an array.

Comment: @Turing85 I'm not sure I understand why you quoted that at me (I linked to the documentation)?

Comment: @Slaw because it sounded like you wanted to imply that `binarySearch(...)` "runs faster" than `O(n)` which is, w.l.o.g., not the case.

Comment: @Slaw I like the `dropWhile` and `takeWhile` approach. Thanks.

Comment: @ttt That will not actually give you anything better than O(n), at least not according to the methods' documentation.

Comment: As RealSkeptic already mentioned, those methods will still be linear and in the worst case still "loop" over all elements; however, it will "break" out of the "loop" early if possible. I would recommend using them only if you are stuck using a `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at both ends of the list, counting indices until you find the first index after or equal to the desired start time, while iterating backwards to get the index of the last time in the period you're looking for.
Something like:

```
int first;
for (LocalDateTime time : timeStampList){
    if (time.compareTo(startTime) < 0){
        first++;
    }else{
        return i + 1;
    }
}

int last = list.length();
while (last > 0){
    LocalDateTime time = timeStampList[last];
    if (time.compareTo(endTime) > 0){
        last -= 1;
    }else{
       return last - 1;
    }
}
```

The subset you'll looking for will then be everything between those indices (inclusive)

Comment: This is still an O(n) operation that loops through most of the list.

Comment: time complexity is still `n` and thus not faster than iterating over all elements.

Comment: The question asks for a method that achieves it's goal: "without looping for all the elements of list" perhaps you should read the question?.

Given that the question doesn't specify whether all timestamps are at regular intervals, the assumption that they're distributed evenly also isn't valid.

Comment: Well, how much of the list will your solution scan if the given time range is not in the list?

Comment: How quickly could you check the first element to ensure it is?

Comment: In an ordered, random-access list, within O(log(n)) time.

Comment: Well, actually, you can check the first and last elements in O(1) time - given it's specified as a List.

Comment: And if you're not checking the first element is before your end of range value and, the last element is after your start of range value BEFORE you doing anything else, you really should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet-E-boolean-E-boolean-) method of `NavigableSet`

> NavigableSet subSet(E fromElement,
>                          boolean fromInclusive,
>                          E toElement,
>                          boolean toInclusive)

It could be like this:

```
NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(yourListWithTimestamps);

//Initialize your start and end date-times:
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-03-01T10:10:10");
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-03-01T22:22:21");

NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> subSet = treeSet.subSet(start, false, end, false);

//Optional - convert it back to list:
List<LocalDateTime> subList = new ArrayList<>(subSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you the following code which doesn't use drop at all:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SublistWithLambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocalDateTime> dates = Arrays.asList(
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(24),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(22),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(20),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(12),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(10),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(7),
                LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(5)
        );

        BiPredicate<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> isLessThan12Hours = (date1, date2) -> {
            Duration duration = Duration.between(date2, date1);
            return duration.toHours() >= 0 && duration.toHours() <= 12;
        };

        List<List<LocalDateTime>> result = IntStream
                .range(0, dates.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> dates.stream().skip(i)
                        .takeWhile(date -> isLessThan12Hours.test(date, dates.get(i)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I hope that this is what you are looking for.